# Images are not found when styling background using URL to locate image in react

Tags: reactjs, directory

I am learning react, hence I am new to react though not new to development. I was creating a slider in which the `<div>` have a background that is to be set using already present images. I think there is mistake somewhere in dynamically allocating the directory of the images although i am not entirely sure.

This is short image of directory

[image of directory](https://i.ibb.co/nMM8Szq/dir.jpg)

I have details of images stored in a `const slides` in which `cover` holds the name of image( like cover1.jpg). When I `console.log(item.cover)` I got the correct names of images, but I can't seem to implement it to correctly represent the directory of images

This is the current code that is written in **featured.js**

```
slides.map((item)=>{
    return(
        <div key={item.id} className="item-slider" 
        style={{background:'url("../images/covers/'+item.cover+'")'}} >
        </div>
    )
})
```

And previously i have tried

```
style={{background:'url(/images/covers/${item.cover})'}}
```

and

```
style={{background:'url("images/covers/${item.cover}")'}}
```

with many different combos of directory

How can i get the images to show and what am i doing wrong. Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: if item.cover is an "object" like you said, it won't work. Maybe try accessing a single name from the object? What's the output look like of item.cover?

Comment: `item.cover` provides a single name at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't Know Why! but it worked when i added another nest

```
slides.map((item)=>{
    return(
        <div key={item.id}>
            <div className="item-slider" 
            style={{background:'url("../images/covers/'+item.cover+'")'}} >
            </div>
        </div>
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using template literals correctly. You're using ' instead of `.

```
style={{background:`url(/images/covers/${item.cover})`}}
```

Comment: I see, its back ticks instead of single quote (Thanks for correction). But i am still unable to locate the images. They are not showing.